# Error: Entrypoint isn't visible within the current project in flutter project

Tags: flutter

> C:\Users\john\AndroidStudioProjects\idelala\lib\main.dart

This is my directory for the project.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: is'nt it visible

Comment: make question clear

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue in Android Studio. In my case it happened because my .iml file got corrupted and on opening the project I would see an error message telling me that it couldn't be opened.

However, the same error message seems to be raised for a number of different reasons. You can see if any of the solutions mentioned in the flutterj issue help resolve your problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2307

If they don't, what worked for me was to "File -> Close Project". Backup and remove all intellij folders and files like .iml files and .idea folder, and then from the Android studio welcome page follow these steps to create a Flutter project from exisiting sources ([reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio)):

1. In the IDE, click Create New Project from the Welcome window or File > New > Project from the main IDE window.
2. Important: Do not use the New > Project from existing sources option for Flutter projects.
3. Select Flutter in the menu, and click Next.
4. Under Project location enter, or browse to, the directory holding your existing Flutter source code files.
5. Click Finish

Note, that if you have any custom run configurations, these are stored in the .idea folder so you back that folder up and after recreating the project move them from the backup folder to the new .idea folder.